# Using css selector in webdriver, gives an error other element would receive the click?

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

So the following code, I am using the first commented out option:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div.show_hide:nth-child(7) > h5:ntchild(1)").click()
```

Other options I have tried:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('// *[ @ id = "show-hide"] / h5').click()

driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#show-hide > h5').click()
```

Sorry about the formatting, the site keeps giving error even when its properly formatted as code.

The [url](https://www.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/get_quote/GetQuoteFO.jsp?underlying=RELIANCE&instrument=FUTSTK&expiry=28SEP2017&type=-&strike=-)

I have a list of stocks and sometimes the code works perfectly but other times like now I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<input>", line 71, in opt_data
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 74, in click
    self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 457, in _execute
return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 233, in execute
self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 194, in check_response
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Element <h5>...</h5> is not clickable at point (791, 654). Other element would receive the click: <h5>...</h5>
  (Session info: chrome=60.0.3112.90)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.27.440174 (e97a722caafc2d3a8b807ee115bfb307f7d2cfd9),platform=Windows NT 10.0.15063 x86_64)
```

I have tried using other `selectors` but nothing seems to `click` the `element` correctly except the one I have in the code currently.

Wondering what I am doing wrong or what would be a better solution.

Comment: which element u want to click

Comment: do u want to click and expand that `Cost of Carry` table?

Comment: I have tried `driver.find_element_by_xpath('// *[ @ id = "show-hide"] / h5').click()`, it works fine with `chrome webdriver`.

Comment: Notice that there're two divs both with `id='show-hide'` ,  could that be the problem?  maybe choose another way to select the element?

Comment: and you should not have two ids that are the same. While browsers eat it, it is not a correct usage.

Comment: sometimes we just don't have control of that

Comment: @CtheSky @iamsankalp89 I want to click the `Other Information` table. @Vladimir M the first option `div.show_hide:nth-child(7) > h5:ntchild(1)` works sporadically and then 6 out of 10 times I get the error I stated.

Answer (score 0):

It would be very difficult to tell you exactly what is wrong, cause it is a valid webdriver behavior. Basically, web driver tells you that another element is visually on top of the one, that you are trying to click. It may be caused by several things:

1) Bad test design (i.e. something is really on top of your element. - check your test scenario and/or element layout

2) Difference in screen resolution/browser size when running the test. - if you are not running headless, then you could visually check what is happening. alternatively, set the browser size to a predefined size before each test start.

3) Very unlikely, malfunction of the web driver...

There one possible work around for such issues, if you are sure that everything is done correctly - fall back to the good old browser.execute_script. You can pass the problematic states of your test scenario by running those in injected  javascript inside the browser itself. However, it will not do the validation, that webdriver does. So use it with care.